# Is it possible to get the system tray with an inactive shell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, shell

On a few external devices we use windows 7 and windows xp and a custom shell (instead of explorer.exe).

Time and again though the problem arises that I would need to right click on a specific icon that normaly is inside the system tray and then use one of the commands that pop up then.

My question is: IS there any way to accomplish this without resetting the shell to explorer.exe and restarting?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you are trying to do. In **some** cases there may be alternatives. As it stands your question is "too broad".

Comment: The question is how can I  "focus" it more? In essence I need to access the right click menu of a custom program that I would normally find in the systems tray. But as the shell is deactivated I have no systems tray (as I have a custom program instead of explorer.exe in the shell entry in the registry). Not sure how I could focus it more? (thus what additional info would be needed there?)

Comment: If it is a custom program then I don't suppose we can help ... you may be able to do something by writing a program to send the appropriate Windows message to the application but that is off-topic for [SU]

Comment: ok that means there is no way beside a custom program or a restart with the explorer shell to be able to see the system tray/interact with it. (had hoped there is some way). tnx